# Rubygems and bundler broken, Psych::SyntaxError

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler

All of these were broken and returned the error message below. I tried everything. Deleted all my rvm stuff with rvm implode. Restarted my computer. Reinstalled rvm and ruby 1.9.3 and STILL Rubygems was broken. (Except for the rubygems that comes with OS X outside rvm, but I needed to fix rvm.)

```
gem
gem -v
gem install
bundle install

psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 4 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I tried searching google and stackoverflow, but I couldn't figure out which file is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the broken file was my ~/.gemrc file. Try checking there for any syntax errors.

Comment: I have opened a bug for rubygems to show proper error, it should be fixed in rubygems 2.1+ => https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/571